# Rails layouts dynamic rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, pjax, turbolinks

I have a Ruby on Rails application that, at it's most basic level consists of two panels, the left and the right side panel. What I want is to use this as a layout, and in the controllers to be able to render like `render <view_name>, <right or left panel>`, so that, in combination with turbolinks, only the left or right side panels are being created dynamically.

I searched the internet but didn't find any examples like mine. I'm sure this is doable but how?
EDIT:it should be able to run in chrome for Android.
One solution would be to render all the views on the first request, and when I click a link panels are hidden and shown, but I don't think this is Ok. Any opinions?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after some research I reached the following conclusion:

With I was trying to do is not possible unless you set some limitations.

Only one of the two panels can render "actions" that are stored in the browsing history. If both panels render actions that are stored in the browsing history it's highly probable that navigation won't work as expected.

With this in mind I realized that what I actually need is to render the navigation aware actions in the left panel, and in the right panel render the other stuff(I call them utilities). For example one thing that I render in such a panel is a Chat-Panel.This is how facebook works with it's chat.

So basically I can user standard turbolinks to handle the requests which store browsing history and something like pjax for the "Utils" panel. The only problem is the Turbolinks completely renders the whole page, even if you send a small piece of html as a response.

To solve this I ended up using wiselinks, which is the perfect combination of turbolinks and pjax. Also, unlike pjax, wiselinks can even handle forms.

Answer (score 1):

Thats unfortunately not possible with turbolinks, neither with pjax itself (to have multiple so called pjax-containers).

Turbolinks always replaces the content of the whole body element.
Pjax always replaces the content of the element with `pjax-container` data attribute.

There are ways to do it of course. Ditching client side javascript frameworks you can perform an ajax request and return a `js` response.

From top of my head you can have view that goes something like this:

**index.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to 'Show', show_path, remote: true %>
```

**controller**

```
def show
  # Do the work, fetch data from database etc.

  # Keeping both formats ensures that when you hit the url directly 
  # the whole page gets rendered as usual (show.html.erb), 
  # when the request is an ajax request using the view snipper above just
  # the javascript for replacing the content of a single panel is rendered (show.js.erb)
  #
  # Rails is smart enough so it should not be required to include the respond_to block
  # in the controller, Rails automagically chooses an appropriate response format
  # based on the request, you only need to have the views in place,
  # but I keep it here so you get a picture.
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
```

**show.js.erb**

```
$('.right-panel').html('<%= j render partial: "something" %>')
```

Comment: I know it is possible if you use only ajax, and handle all the hard work on the client side, but I really want to avoid this. I will look into pjax, I never heard of it before. I'll edit the question, I forgot to specify that it has to work on an android device with chrome for android.

Comment: I will try this when I get home. However I don't understand what <%= j ...%> does.Will this render the view?If yes what kind of response should I send? Pls read my edit with the suggestion I posted

Comment: Well, this basically returns a javascript code that gets executed on a client when the request finishes. This snippet tells jQuery to replace the content of `.right-panel` with whatever is passed as argument to `html` method. In this case Rails renders a partial into the argument. The `j` helper escapes javascript code (carriage returns and single and double quotes for JavaScript segments), its an alias for `escape_javascript` helper method.

Comment: Well I see how this could work. Only problem is that this would be not in sync with my data. For example, if "something" is a list of "books", I will always see the books that existed when I made the initial load of the page.However, if I use my technique(described in my question) I can use WebSockets to keep that books list in sync. What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: Of course, you get the data current in the time user clicked the link/ajax request was made. If you want the data to be always in sync with server and automatically update when the server gets updated thats totally a different question. You can use websockets/long polling for that but the logic would be more complicated on the both client and the server. The only framework I know of that supports that out of the box is `Meteor.js`. Imho, Realtime with Rails is hard. If you want get down this path look at `Faye` or `Socket.io` but I find it too much overhead for most use cases.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will look into these frameworks. Can you please look at my suggested solution, to one with hidden divs? Can you please tell me your view on this options?Thanks.

Comment: I don't think I fully understand your proposed solution. Sure you can do that, but how you gonna update the data? Background refresh using ajax when user click to display the panel?

Comment: Rails is good in two things: 1) render a webpage, you click a link, render another webpage. 2) serving JSON and let client side handle that and update the view. If you want a realtime feeling without page rerendered all the time consider moving the rendering logic to client side using Ember, Backbone, Angular or another and use Rails just as an API for getting data to the browser.

Comment: You helped me with you answer so I gave you an upvote but I think my own answer covers better my problem so I marked that as the accepted answer.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if it's a best practice but I needed something similar and here is what I did:

I have this layout

```
1st panel | 2nd panel  | 3rd panel
Site Menu | Posts List | Article Show
```

To always render posts list, I needed to add to my application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :set_posts

  def set_posts
    @posts = Post.all
  end
end
```

Then in my layout, here is what I did:

```
%body
    #site-wrapper
      #site-canvas
        #reading-list
          #reading-nav-block 
          = render 'posts/list'

        #article-show
          #article-nav-block
          #article-content-block
            = yield
        #site-menu
          #logo-block
          .menu
```

Basically I extracted posts#index into the posts#_list partial and set the variable, rendered post/_list in all layouts. Here is the result:

[image]